# Android imageview with layerdrawable

Tags: android, android-imageview

My program has a gridview with imageview(s) as child views. I want to give feedback to users when a particular imageview is clicked by showing a translucent layer and a tick mark over the original image. I'm using a layerdrawable with 3 layers. I tested the code by writing a small application and it works perfectly. But it is not working inside gridview.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
{

    baseimage = ((ImageView)v).getDrawable(); //This is the original image thumbnail
layers = new Drawable[3];
layers[0] = baseimage;
layers[1] = white_color;// white_color is a ColorDrawable with colour = 2147483647
layers[2] = tick_mark;

    if(!selected[(int)id])//selected is a boolean array to store if an imageview is selected or not
    {
Toast.makeText(this,"selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//layers[1].setVisible(true,true);
//layers[2].setVisible(true,true);

translucent = new LayerDrawable(layers);
((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(translucent);
v.invalidate();
selected[(int)id] = true;
    }
    else
    {
    //((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(baseimage);
    //layers[1].setVisible(false,true);
//layers[2].setVisible(false,true);
translucent.invalidateSelf();
v.invalidate();
((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(null);
((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(baseimage);
Toast.makeText(this,((ImageView)v).getDrawable().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

selected[(int)id] = false;
    }

}
```

When I ran the code, the layerdrawable is displayed correctly first time and I when click it again, the imageview showed no change. If I click it for the third time, a new layerdrawable  is added to already existing layerdrawable, the white translucent layer gets added on top every time.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem.

The first time you enter the `onItemClick()` the `baseimage=v.getDrawable()` is only an image. However, the second time the `onItemClick()` is called, the `baseimage=v.getDrawable()` may represent an image + white color + a tick overlay. Therefore, even if the `if(!selected[(int)id])` case executes, you will still see the overlay.

Comment: Brian, thank-you very much for your reply. Now I'm trying to use universal image loader in my project instead of my own code. But if you give me any solution then I'll use my code itself.